# Asynchronous web service in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, asynchronous

I'm getting information from some Web Service, but I would like the methods that I'm calling just be asynchronous, because the petition is taking so long so that makes the website loads slowly.

I'm currently using the normal SOAP call

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://xxxx.com/webservices/json.asmx?WSDL");

$result = $client->__soapCall($id, $parameters);
```

Can someone help me please

Comment: Even if you implemented asynchronous call from PHP, you still have to wait X amount of time until the result arrives back to the PHP script. Your site will still hang and you will have achieved nothing. Implement loading indicators in your app (client side) and don't perform too many SOAP requests towards the slow service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal approach for this is not an asynchronous strategy in the server side only, since that does not comply with how php works. Instead this strategy is applied:

You process the request and respond a html page to the client that has container elements where the results of the slow API calls go. But the containers are left empty or contain a placeholder. In addition a client side logic is delivered, so javascript, that registers a handler to the document ready event on the client side. Inside that handler it makes ajax requests back to the server, typically one request per API call that has to be performed. The payload received in the ajax requests is used to fill the containers inside the html with the final data.

That way the generation and rendering of the page/view itself is decoupled from waiting for the API calls completely. In addition the strategy is transparent, the user can see that additional data is fetched which makes the waiting period more acceptable from a psychological points of view.

You could think of a variant of that strategy which already registers server based jobs executing the actual API calls and buffering the results. That way you keep the delay slow of the round trip of sending out a page and waiting for the ajax calls to come in. However the challenge here is to keep the connection between those jobs and the original request with its subsequent ajax calls which is not an easy task. Typically the advantage does not justify the additional effort at all.

So as a bottom line one can say that typically no asynchronous strategy in pure php is implemented. Instead the original request is split into several separate ones. Only the first request is processed and responded to right away, independent of any slow API calls. Then, in parallel, ajax requests trigger the API calls and add the resulting information to the response to the first request.

Answer (score 3):

3 years later, I think people are starting to catch on that "Asynchronous" does not mean "multithreaded". Take NodeJS for example - it's nearly as strongly single-threaded as PHP, yet also powerfully asynchronous. And PHP has this capability too, if you know where to look for (though, admittedly, it could be better developed)

The basis of this is the [Curl library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), which includes the inconspicuous `curl_multi_*` functions. With this you can fire off several HTTP requests in parallel and process the responses as they come in, or wait for all to complete, or whatever. And all this happens on a single thread, fully asynchronously. You can periodically poll for the status (which takes up some CPU resources), or you can use [`curl_multi_select()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-select.php) which will actually suspend your thread (like [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)) until some activity occurs. All the magic happens in the OS kernel itself, meaning it's as efficient as can get.

So how do you get this to work with SOAP? Well, as it turns out, you can inherit from the  [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) class and override the [`__doRequest()`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php) method. And probably a bunch of other methods too. And voilà - you have an asynchronous SOAP client!

This is a bit of work, and Curl can be tricky to get right, so you might want to use some code other people have written already. One nice library is [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) which wraps Curl in an easier to use wrapper. Or if you search for "php async soap client" you can get several libraries where people have already done all the hard work and you can just take an off-the-shelf async `SoapClient` derivative. For example, the first few results on Google give me [ReactPHP-Soap](https://github.com/clue/reactphp-soap), [PHP-Parallel-Soap](https://github.com/meabed/php-parallel-soap) and [Async-Soap-Guzzle](https://github.com/meng-tian/async-soap-guzzle). I think all of these are also available as [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) packages.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous - it is not about php.
Script works as is, line by line and we can do nothing here.
If you wnat to do things fast (closer to asyncronous), u should remake your app architecture.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture

At first you should have some "bus" of events, one scripts put there some commands, other scripts (demons) listens and executes this commands.

The profit here is that to push some command to bus is much faster (we even dont need to wait for response) then do actual work. Actual work ( $client = new SoapClient(... ) here should be done by other script.

sorry for english

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on whether you need the output from web service or not.

If you need it, go with the Ajax way or service way. You could also use queues to manage jobs, like Redis or beanstalkd.

If you don't need output, and just want to call the api, then you could also put that code in another script, and call it in the background, like

```
shell_exec('php script.php someargs >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Notice the redirects, they are needed.